# SQL Server compression

Tags: sql-server, compression

When inserting into a compressed table, will the data be compressed into the log file or will it be compressed when the checkpoint runs and the data is written to the data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `row compression` is used, data rows have no more `FixedVar` regular row format, but `CD`(column descriptor) format.

So when you insert a row into a table that has row compression enabled, the row is formatted (in memory!) in this new CD format, and in this format it will be written to disk.

When you apply `page compression`, the things are different. Page compression is not applied on every row insertion:

> SQL Server stores the data in page-compressed format only when the
>   page  is full and compression leads to significant space savings. When
>   a page is full, SQL Server performs compression and evaluates if the
>   newly compressed page can store either five more rows or 25 percent
>   more rows than before the compression. If that is the case, then page
>   compression is retained and SQL Server stores the data in
>   page-compressed format. Otherwise, the page compression is discarded
>   and data is stored in row-compressed format.

Another thing to note:

> Neither  transaction log   records for data modifications nor the
>   version store in  tempdb  supports page compression. SQL Server needs
>   to decompress the page and remove anchor and dictionary records every
>   time a row needs to be placed in the version store or written to the
>   transaction log.

The last thing to consider:

> Page compression consists of three different  stages. First, SQL
>   Server performs row compression on the rows.

So as soon as you apply any type of compression, the rows are stored in CD format, and they are in this format in memory (prior to be written to log/data files)